64-bit Linux and x86_64-v1 micro-architecture
At this writing (November 2024) are there still any currently-maintained 64-bit Linux distributions that install and run successfully on x86_64-v1 micro-architecture level hardware?
Or do all currently maintained 64-bit distributions require a CPU supporting at minimum the x86_64-v2 instruction set?

hm, do you have an example of any non-CPU-vendor-owned distro of the opposite, i.e., one that actually requires v2?

@MarcusMüller RHEL 9 requires x86-64-v2, RHEL 10 will require v3; Tumbleweed requires v2.

@StephenKitt super interesting! That simplifies a lot of CPU checking that libvolk is currently doing, awesome!

You mean other than source-based distros such as Gentoo?

I think this ultimately should be more of a question of which distributions require higher than v1 than which ones can handle v1 CPUs, considering that the list is a lot shorter for distributions with higher requirements.

As of 2024-11-19, a significant majority of Linux distributions that ship 64-bit x86 packages ship all code compiled for baseline x86-64 (equivalent to AMD K8 or Intel Prescott hardware). There are some exceptions to this, with some distros requiring x86-64-v2 or x86-64-v3, and some of the arguably smarter distros looking into providing an option to use such a build but still providing baseline builds as well, but as a general rule they are the a relative minority unless you only look at ‘big’ distros.
Part of this comes down to a desire to preserve compatibility, but a nontrivial part of it also comes down to the fact that both GCC and Clang will produce only baseline x86-64 code unless you explicitly tell them to use other things, and most distros do not explicitly tell them to do other things. A much smaller part also comes down to the fact that whether or not a higher microarchitectural level has a significant impact on x86-64 is highly dependent on exactly what you’re doing. A small handful of instructions in x86-64-v2 are universally useful (cmpxchg16b is the probably the best example), but a lot of stuff in the higher levels (including much of x86-64-v2) is much more specific (for example, popcnt is very useful for a small handful of very specific things (to the point that both GCC and Clang can recognize simple implementations of what it does in C/C++ and will replace them with that single instruction), but absolutely useless outside of those cases).

GCC7 and later never inline lock cmpxchg16b regardless of -m options, so 16-byte atomic load/store/RMW are always getting runtime dispatch to the optimal libatomic function supported by the hardware we're running on.  (Same as with memcpy / strchr etc, via a dynamic linker resolver function that selects a function pointer, since shared-library function calls always go through a GOT pointer so there's no extra level of indirection.)  x86-64-v3 (AVX2+FMA+BMI1/BMI2) allows cheaper 16-byte atomic load/store using vmovaps instead of lock cmpxchg16b. And cheaper variable-count shifts (1 uop)

See https://gcc.gnu.org/legacy-ml/gcc-patches/2017-01/msg02344.html re: the change in GCC7.  (And an older answer of mine on How can I implement ABA counter with c++11 CAS? which I've updated a bit, but not since Intel/AMD documented that the AVX feature bit implies 16-byte aligned load/store are atomic.)

x86-64-v2 is SSE4, which has some nice stuff for auto-vectorizing integer loops, especially ones that work with different element sizes (like int8_t and int32_t).  GCC -O2 will only auto-vectorize in the cheapest cases, like when the loop count is a known constant and is a multiple of the vector width. But Clang -O2 will auto-vectorize pretty aggressively.

Debian’s amd64 variant still supports all 64-bit x86 CPUs, including the “v1” baseline (compare the corresponding section for i386, which mentions unsupported 32-bit CPUs).
Apart from RHEL and Tumbleweed, I think most distributions still support the v1 baseline. Ubuntu has v3 test images available, but the distribution default is still v1.
